# watch: true for nested objects - NuxtJS (Vue), latest version

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs

I have a form with many fields attached to a data - `this.myData`:

```
 data: function() {

  return {
    isDataChanged: false,
    myData: {},
    myChangedData: {
        default: '',
        default1: {},
        default2: []
    },
  }
},
```

`myData` is populated from a response from the server and it populates the form values.
`myChangedData` is for the new values, which are changed `v-on:input="onChangeMyData($event, 'default')"`:

```
   onChangeMyData(e, name, required = false){
          const val = e.target.value.trim();

          this.myChangedData[name] = val;
          console.log(this.myChangedData)

          this.checkIsmyDataChanged();
      },
```

I can use the same method, providing a key as a second param. With the method `checkIsmyDataChanged` I am checking is it changed some field in the form. This method loops through  `myChangedData` and compares its properties with `changedData` and if there is a difference `this.isDataChanged = true`.

The problem is that, I have a complicated structure of mydata/mydatachanged. `default1` has objects in it and `default1` is an array of objects. This means that, I can't use `onChangeMyData`, but other methods with different checks (validations) and now I need to call in all of them `this.checkIsmyDataChanged();`.

I created a watch for `myChangedData`:

```
 watch:{
      myChangedData: {
          handler: function (newVal) {
              console.log('change')

          },
          deep: true
      },
  },
```

, but it doesn't execute on change data

Comment: seems like an xy problem, on editing an item just deep copy myData into a myDataEdit model and use the myDataEdit on the v-model not a change event, then on saving the item, copy it back as a whole into myData, or if cancel just reset the model, no watcher needed then, i.e https://playcode.io/721729/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try with `Vue.set` ? [Source](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html)

Change `this.myChangedData[name] = val;` to

```
this.$set(this.myChangedData, 'name', val)
```

Thanks to that, the modification on the object should be detected and execute the watcher.

Comment: you mean `this.$set(this.myChangedData, name, val)`? though it wont help

Comment: thank you both. The solution with `$set` works.

Comment: Just to extend the answer, when you need to delete a property, with `delete(this.myChangedData[name])` will be the same problem, but there is `this.$delete(this.myChangedData, 'name')`